# Relationship between heat coefficient and conductance

Tags: power-electronics, temperature, heat

I'm involved in a project and part of it involves heat coefficient and heat conductance. What's the relationship between the two, given that the SI unit for heat coefficient is \$W/mK\$ and the SI unit for heat conductance is \$W/m^2K\$?

\$W\$ - Heat Energy (Watts/Joules per second)
\$m\$ - Length
\$m^2\$ - Area
\$K\$ - Difference in Temperature (Kelvin)

Does anyone know the above parameters for steel? Especially heat conductance.

Thank you.

Comment: What does googling this tell you?

Comment: Googling doesn't really explain much on the conductance. Mostly heat co-efficient.

Comment: Actually, you've got it backwards: [heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) is \$W/m^2K\$ and [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) is \$W/mK\$.

Comment: Mechanical/Thermal Engineering problem?

Comment: I appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic relationship between the two. [Heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) ( \$W/m^2K\$) is a measure of how readily heat moves across the interface between two different materials, while [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) (\$W/mK\$) is a measure of how easily it moves within a single material.